# If statement inside variables use without eval() method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I try to check a condition using php variable like..

```
if ($amount. $row['condition']. $row['amount']) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

but the condition always return true value ,i also echo the single variable it will show the value and also do `dd($amount. $rom['condition']. $rom['amount']);` it will show **"500>1000"** ,i remove the double qutes and manually past value in if condition it will show false with this condition,  how to solve and write this condition ?

Comment: With the . you are connecting them, use === or > or < What is the condition?

Comment: @Grumpy > is the condition the condition is dynamically change

Comment: you missed the echo. Please add the echo before $amount and check. like  
echo $amount. $row['condition']. $row['amount']

Comment: Shouldnt it be someting like if ($amount >  $row['amount'])

Comment: Not sure turn an **if operator** into a variable is possible. Moreover, what you show, your variables will be considered as a concatenated string

Comment: @Hkachhia show syntax error it will in if condition

Comment: @Grumpy ($amount > $row['amount']) it will working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a match or switch like so:

```php
<?php

# match php 8+
$result = match ($row['condition']) {
    '==' => $amount == $row['amount'],
    '<' => $amount < $row['amount'],
    '>' => $amount > $row['amount'],
};

# switch
switch ($row['condition']) {
    case '==':
        $result = $amount == $row['amount'];
        break;
    case '<':
        $result = $amount < $row['amount'];
        break;
    case '>':
        $result = $amount > $row['amount'];
        break;
};

var_dump($result);
```

[Try online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=40664f309cd275f9eacad6cedcf39d73&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) show this error

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval()`

```
$condition = $amount. $row['condition']. $row['amount'];
if (eval("return $condition;")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

**Important Note:** Before using `eval()` make sure you have sanitized user input while inserting into database.

Docs for input sanitization : https://www.cloudways.com/blog/prevent-laravel-xss-exploits/

Comment: Beware the use of eval is not advised as it is executed as arbitrary code, and if you get that from user input, and don't validate it properly, it can expose your app to some attacks.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) show this error

Comment: @LeenaPatel how it will be work

Comment: Ohh i forgot to put quotes. need to add quotes to function properly. check edited answer

Comment: @MarceloZárate I understand your point. Here the OP wants to check condition dynamically and for that `eval()` is life saver. Furthermore it is not used for searching in database or inserting in database so as per my belief it wont do any harm to the application.

Comment: The data is clearly coming from a database, so we can 99% be sure this is user input. So this could definitely harm the application/server if the user input is not sanitized.

Comment: this code have some security issues..., but it's working well

Comment: @Andrew You need to sanitize input before inserting into database. That would be best for preventing your applications from security attacks.

Comment: @MarceloZárate Thank you for pointing this out. I have updated my answer so that anyone uses it makes sure to sanitize inputs while inserting into database.

Answer (score 1):

I've never faced such scenario, but I would imagine something like:

```
if ($row['condition'] == "==") {
    if ($amount == $row['amount']) 
        return true
    else
        return false
}
if ($row['condition'] == ">") {
    if ($amount > $row['amount']) 
        return true
    else
        return false
}
if ($row['condition'] == "<") {
    if ($amount < $row['amount']) 
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Comment: Using a `switch` here would look cleaner though

Comment: it's ok , but i have many condition like above my code write this code it will be heavy

Comment: Welcome to refactoring, haha